How to create joined records as embedded XML elements in SELECT ... FOR XML?
I got stuck when generating XML document (IDOC) from SQL select.
The XML should look like this:
<IDOC>
  <MASTER>
    .... some master elements ...
    <NESTED1>
      ... 1st nested element instance 1...
    </NESTED1>
    <NESTED1>
      ... 1st nested element instance 2...
    </NESTED1>
    <NESTED2>
      ... instance 1
    </NESTED2>
    <NESTED2>
      ... instance 2
    </NESTED2>
   </MASTER>
<IDOC>

But what I get is this:
<IDOC>
  <MASTER>
    .... some master elements ...
    <NESTED1>
      ... 1st nested element instance 1...
    </NESTED1>
    <NESTED2>
      ... instance 1
    </NESTED2>
   </MASTER>
<IDOC>
<IDOC>
  <MASTER>
    .... some master elements ...
    <NESTED1>
      ... 1st nested element instance 1...
    </NESTED1>
    <NESTED2>
      ... instance 2
    </NESTED2>
   </MASTER>
<IDOC>
<IDOC>
  <MASTER>
    .... some master elements ...
    <NESTED1>
      ... 1st nested element instance 2...
    </NESTED1>
    <NESTED2>
      ... instance 1
    </NESTED2>
   </MASTER>
<IDOC>
<IDOC>
  <MASTER>
    .... some master elements ...
    <NESTED1>
      ... 1st nested element instance 2...
    </NESTED1>
    <NESTED2>
      ... instance 2
    </NESTED2>
   </MASTER>
<IDOC>

The SQL generating dataset for XML is like this:
select 
   MASTER.COL1 as 'MASTER/COL1',
   MASTER.COL2 as 'MASTER/COL2',
   NESTED1.DATA1 as 'MASTER/NESTED1/DATA1',
   NESTED2.TEXT1 as 'MASTER/NESTED2/TEXT1',
from MASTER
join NESTED1 on NESTED1.MASTER_PK = MASTER.MASTER_PK
join NESTED2 on NESTED2.MASTER_PK = MASTER.MASTER_PK
for xml PATH, ROOT('IDOC')

Perhaps I do not read the documentaion correctly, but I did not find any example if what I need is possible and what directives or parameters should be used.
As for the minimal reproducible example related to https://dbfiddle.uk/eZWVmVKL :
the desired output would be:
<MASTER>
 <ID>158</ID>
 <NAME>Antenna</NAME>

  <DESCRIPTION>
    <LANG>CZ</LANG>
    <TEXT>Antena Yagi 6el</TEXT>
  </DESCRIPTION>

  <DESCRIPTION>
    <LANG>EN</LANG>
    <TEXT>Antenna Yagi 6 elements</TEXT>
  </DESCRIPTION>

  <PERFORMANCE>
    <PARAM>GAIN</PARAM>
    <UNIT>dBi</UNIT>
    <VALUE>8.5</VALUE>
  </PERFORMANCE>

  <PERFORMANCE>
   <PARAM>F/B RATIO</PARAM>
    <UNIT>dB</UNIT>
    <VALUE>15</VALUE>
  </PERFORMANCE>

  <PERFORMANCE>
    <PARAM>LENGTH</PARAM>
    <UNIT>cm</UNIT>
    <VALUE>120</VALUE>
  </PERFORMANCE>

</MASTER>


It is considered a bad practice to embed sequential numbers into XML element names. If you really need sequential numbers, it is better to use attributes for that. Along the  the following: <root><row id=1>...</row><row id=2>...</row></root>

Misunderstanding, @YitzhakKhabinsky. I created general example in order not to disclose reserved company information. NESTED1 and NESTED2 could as well be PARTS and COLORS, for example. Same applies to DATA1, TEXT1. These are example element names not related to ordering or data values.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Please provide a minimal reproducible example, and, we will provide you a working solution via T-SQL. The answer that you marked as Answer is not an Answer without a working code.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example: ##1-4. Combination of T-SQL and XQuery is a solution. We accept the challenge!

https://dbfiddle.uk/eZWVmVKL

Thanks for the dbfiddle. Alas, it is covering only ##1,4. Please edit your question, and add #3: Desired output, based on the sample data.

I provided a raw draft answer. Still waiting for a desired output.

You don't group by MASTER.MASTER_PK so you get 1 row for each tuple(master, nested1, nested2) generated by your JOINs, once you will group by MASTER.MASTER_PK you will have another problem: you will get a cross product of all NESTED1 and NESTED2 related to that MASTER_PK, so the solution is to generate the "NESTED1" and "NESTED2" list of nodes with subqueries aggregating the results in the MASTER node.

P.S. so I have to create the embedded element sets separately and then find another way how to compose the final XML, there is no support for this in MS-SQL, I suppose.

@p3consulting, would it it possible to re-work your answer, and provide a working T-SQL code?

Sorry, not fluent enough in SQLServer dialect once it concerns XML (or JSON) generation..

A small and incomplete (missing the IDOC level) POC: https://dbfiddle.uk/NaqrgaP8... had to use FOR XML EXPLICIT to get what I wanted but I am not good at SQLServer, maybe there is something easier (fyi in ORA: https://dbfiddle.uk/hoNnewkh)

Simpler version for SQLServer: https://dbfiddle.uk/9ZlkhoRq

Please try the following solution based on T-SQL and XQuery.
It is following the same minimal reproducible example paradigm. You copy it as-is to SSMS, run it, and it is working as expected, producing the desired output.
SQL
USE tempdb;
GO

-- DDL and sample data population, start
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS popis;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS master;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS performance;

CREATE TABLE master (
   master_pk int identity(1,1) primary key,
   item_id int,
   item_name varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO master VALUES 
( 158, 'Antenna');

create table popis (
  master_pk int,
  POPIS_PK int identity(1,1) primary key,
  LANG varchar(3),
  TEXT varchar(50)
);
insert into popis values 
(1, 'CZ', 'Antena Yagi 6el'), 
(1, 'EN', 'Antenna Yagi 6 elements');

create table performance ( 
  master_pk int, 
  performance_pk int identity(1,1),
  param varchar(50),
  unit varchar(10),
  value numeric(8,3)
);
insert into performance 
values (1, 'GAIN', 'dBi', 8.5),
(1, 'F/B RATIO', 'dB', 15),
(1, 'LENGTH', 'cm', 120);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT m.item_id AS [ID], m.item_name AS [NAME]
    , (SELECT po.LANG, po.TEXT
        FROM popis AS po
        WHERE po.master_pk = m.master_pk
        FOR XML PATH('DESCRIPTION'), TYPE)
    , (SELECT pe.param AS [PARAM], pe.unit AS [UNIT], pe.value AS [VALUE]
        FROM performance AS pe
        WHERE pe.master_pk = m.master_pk
        FOR XML PATH('PERFORMANCE'), TYPE)
FROM dbo.master  AS m
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('MASTER');

Output
<MASTER>
  <ID>158</ID>
  <NAME>Antenna</NAME>
  <DESCRIPTION>
    <LANG>CZ</LANG>
    <TEXT>Antena Yagi 6el</TEXT>
  </DESCRIPTION>
  <DESCRIPTION>
    <LANG>EN</LANG>
    <TEXT>Antenna Yagi 6 elements</TEXT>
  </DESCRIPTION>
  <PERFORMANCE>
    <PARAM>GAIN</PARAM>
    <UNIT>dBi</UNIT>
    <VALUE>8.500</VALUE>
  </PERFORMANCE>
  <PERFORMANCE>
    <PARAM>F/B RATIO</PARAM>
    <UNIT>dB</UNIT>
    <VALUE>15.000</VALUE>
  </PERFORMANCE>
  <PERFORMANCE>
    <PARAM>LENGTH</PARAM>
    <UNIT>cm</UNIT>
    <VALUE>120.000</VALUE>
  </PERFORMANCE>
</MASTER>


well, this is exactly NOT the desired format as there is more than one records and the master repeats

I hope now you understand the importance of a minimal reproducible example. All four ##1-4 are very important. I need from you #3 - desired output. Please edit your original question, and add all ##1-4 without dbfiddler. Directly in the original question.

Did you have a chance to try the proposed solution?
